# Messenger for voice calls

Tags: windows, skype, voip, instant-messaging

I have been using Skype for a very long time, but lately I have been facing a lot of issues with the voice clarity. What messenger or VOIP clients that you know out of experience that are better than Skype for voice communication ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [Gizmo5](http://gizmo5.com/pc/)

Its an open-source VoIP softphone that enables free or minimally expensive calls worldwide. Its spinoff, SIPphone.com, is a startup offering more complex, business-oriented tools that use Gizmo’s protocols, including PSTN (public switched telephone network) gateways, voice mail and SIP (Session Initiation Protocol)/PSTN network peering. Gizmo features Call In and Call Out (similar to SkypeIn and SkypeOut). typically for 1.9 cents per minute, instant messaging, and the ability to record conversations or map where caller and receiver are located. Pro: Available for Windows, Linux and Mac platforms. Con: Umm...

Comment: It's better than skype in terms of call quality though i will not consider switching coz the interface is very unfriendly

Answer (score 3):

I've been using Google Talk.